# Hover(), mouseenter(), mouseover(), etc jumping back and forth

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, jquery-hover, mouseenter

I am trying to make a situation when you hover over an image then it will hide an image and show another. and the other way around when you hover out.

I have tried using all the various hover effects that comes to mind like mouseenter, mouseover, hover, etc.

They all cause the same problem. If i very firmly and quickly drag my cursor into the field of action then it will give me the desired effect. however if i slowly drag my cursor into the field of action then it will jump between the images a couple of times before finally stopping at the correct image.

this looks very unprofessional and i want it to be much more consequent doing this action so that no matter if i do it slow or fast then it will only jump once.

this is my script:

```
$("#DenmarkMap").hide();
$("#InfoBadge1").hover(function(){
    $("#InfoLogo").hide("puff");
    $("#DenmarkMap").show("puff");
}, function(){
    $("#DenmarkMap").hide("puff");
    $("#InfoLogo").show("puff");
});
```

this is a non working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ydeLvxx2/

hope you guys can help me figure this out.

Comment: Your jsfiddle didn't include jQuery, here's a fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/ydeLvxx2/1/. It's still hard to figure out what you're trying to do, though.

Comment: Yeah and i can understand that because that fiddle works as i want it to.. You need to imagine that when i hover over the images in my end then it jumps between the images a couple of times before stopping. In the fiddle it just replaces the images with no jumping back and forth.

Comment: Take a look at `stop()`: https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure Javascript solution (no jQuery needed)

https://jsfiddle.net/uL0hpxbu/
Update: version with CSS3 "puff" effect: https://jsfiddle.net/230ta4tk/2/

Here is how the main `script` looks like:

```
    var InfoBadge1 = document.getElementById("InfoBadge1");
    var InfoLogo = document.getElementById("InfoLogo");
    var DenmarkMap = document.getElementById("DenmarkMap");

    InfoBadge1.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      InfoLogo.classList.toggle("puff");
      DenmarkMap.classList.toggle("puff");
    });
    InfoBadge1.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
      InfoLogo.classList.toggle("puff");
      DenmarkMap.classList.toggle("puff");
    });
```

and CSS part (just an example, change it as you want)

```
    #DenmarkMap {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      transition: .5s all;
    }
    #InfoLogo {
      position: absolute;
      left: 250px;
      top: 120px;
      transition: .5s all;
    }
    #InfoBadge1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 120px;
    }
    .puff {
      transform: scale(1.2);
      opacity: 0;
    }
```

and HTML:

```
<img id="InfoBadge1" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100/803580/ffffff&text=InfoBadge1" alt="" />
<img id="InfoLogo" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100/803580/ffffff&text=InfoLogo" alt="" />
<img id="DenmarkMap" class="puff" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100/3c8036/ffffff&text=DenmarkMap" alt="" />
```

Comment: You are missing one vital thing and that is the "puff" effect. How would you implement it into your code?

Comment: @Nulle What is the puff effect? If you mean some kind of fade-in-out then it can be solved easily with CSS3, here is one possible solution https://jsfiddle.net/230ta4tk/  Which is basically replacing `display:none` with `opacity: 0` in css and adding `transition: .5s all;` and then using `.style.opacity = 0;` or `.style.opacity = 1;` in Javascript

Comment: it is jquery. notice i write show("puff"); by doing that an animation effect takes place.

https://api.jqueryui.com/puff-effect/

Comment: Here is the solution with a "puff" effect https://jsfiddle.net/230ta4tk/3/  Let me know if it is the best solution then I can update the main code above.

Comment: We are getting really close. Transition wise it is no longer jumping. So thats a good thing. However My DenmarkMap is not being affected as intended. And i can guess it has something to do with the way i have css styled. can you please try and use my css code regarding #DenmarkMap and see if you can get it to work still? 

right now the only thing that is happening to DenmarkMap is that it is being scaled up on mouseover and then scaled down again on mouseout.

Comment: InfoLogo is doing exactly as it is supposed to. but that is also way simpler css styled than DenmarkMap

Comment: found out that if i remove my opacity: 0.9; from my DenmarkMap css then your code works. do you know why that is ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not bind your hover's `mouseleave`/`mouseout` event to the same image, because you've **just hidden it**.

Instead, consider binding the `hover` functions to the parent DOM node (a DIV for example):

```
<div id="images">
  <img id="InfoBadge1" src="./Photos/DenmarkInfoBadge.png"> 
  <img id="InfoLogo" src="./Photos/InfoLogo.png">
  <img id="DenmarkMap" src="./Photos/DenmarkMap.png">
</div>
```

Your javascript can then become:

```
$("#DenmarkMap").hide();
$("#images").hover(function(){
    $("#InfoLogo").hide("puff");
    $("#DenmarkMap").show("puff");
}, function(){
    $("#DenmarkMap").hide("puff");
    $("#InfoLogo").show("puff");
});
```

Comment: I am sorry but this gives me the same result. still glitching back and forth.